# In Armenian, which parts of each letter are intrinsic and must be demarcated from joining up strokes in joined-up handwriting?

Tags: orthography, armenian

My question [1] is about handwritten Armenian [2], but to illustrate what I am asking I will first say something about English and Russian, languages which are likely to be known by larger proportions of the site's readership. Handwritten lower-case "a" and "l" (English) and "а" and "л" (Russian) might reasonably be rendered as follows:

[image]

And when we join up the digraphs, we might reasonably write them like this:

[image]

As you can see, the "exit stroke" of the English "a" has merged with the "entry stroke" of the "l". The reason this is considered acceptable is that these strokes are not considered to be an intrinsic part of each letter. Since between two letters you only need a single joining-up stroke, it's fine to merge an exit stroke with a following entry stroke.

The position with the Russian "а" and "л" is different. It would not be considered correct to join the two letters like this:

[image]

Why not? The answer is that the small oblique stroke on the left of the "л" in the first image *is*  considered to be an intrinsic part of that letter. It is not a joining stroke and therefore it cannot be merged with the joining stroke that leads out of the preceding "а". This rule for handwritten "л", "м", and "я" is usually something that needs to be pointed out clearly when a native English speaker is learning Russian as a foreign language.

What I would like to know is how to write joined-up [3]  Armenian. **Which parts of which letters are intrinsic, and which are joining strokes?** **What kind of joining strokes are in common use?**

I have consulted the following books without becoming any wiser on the matter:

- Anahit Avetisyan, "Eastern Armenian: Comprehensive Self-Study Language Course"
- Dora Sakayan, "Eastern Armenian for the English-Speaking World"
- Sarah Neill, "Handbook of Armenian"

**Notes**

1. Before posting this, I checked with the [help file](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and referred to [this question](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/would-questions-about-writing-systems-be-off-topic) on Meta to check whether it was on-topic. It is.
2. I do not know whether the answer to the question varies according to whether a person is writing Classical, Western, or Eastern Armenian, nor whether in written Eastern Armenian it varies between the Traditional and Reformed orthographies. The case I am most interested in is the reformed orthography of Eastern Armenian, as used today by most people in Armenia.
3. "Joined-up" handwriting is a term used in British English. In US English the term "cursive" is preferred.

Comment: I'm not convinced this question is meaningful. Letters are essentially arbitrary, and the forms they take when joined do not necessarily have an obvious relationship to other forms they take. Consider Arabic script, where even in printing, letters take considerably different forms depending on whether they are joined before, after, or both. The "distinctive part" of ta/ba/ya is minimal; but if you finished a word with a non-final form of one of these it would be hard to read.

Comment: When you say you consulted the books, did you actually find examples of how to write each letter in cursive? It is quite common that older language textbooks have such pages.

Comment: I think the question is meaningful, because I have a clue what he's asking, I just have no idea what the answer is. Letters, sounds and words are *conventional* (arbitrary, if you want), but not random). We do better at talking about the "distinctive part" of phonemes because we have better theories of sounds as opposed to graphemes.

Comment: @legatrix - Avetisyan and Sakayan show handwritten forms but only for each letter individually. Neill doesn't show any handwriting and encourages her readers to copy the printed letters (!) I was going to paste a copy of the handwritten forms for each letter but couldn't find an image that was definitely in the public domain.

Comment: Interesting. In that case I was going to suggest that this strikes me as prototypical knowing-how rather than knowing-that. Once you know how, you may be able to formulate the rules. So, first learn the individual cursive elements, and then practise copying out manuscripts. Then you will be in a position to answer the question yourself.

Comment: @ruffle also, there is work by Brenden Lake, a former student of Josh Tenenbaum at MIT, on the essential strokes of letters. It's really cool work and it's the closest thing I know to what you are asking for. He might even have included Armenian in his datasets.

Comment: This is an excellent question, and well-asked. It is a question that anyone learning a language with a new script on their own invariably faces, and it’s nearly always very, very difficult to find answers. Whenever books give handwritten forms of letters, they’re always (well, perhaps not with Arabic, but in general) isolated rather than in context. I don’t know the answer to this either – to the rather limited extent I’ve written (Classical) Armenian by hand, it’s been fairly non-joined-up.

Comment: This is not a bad question, but out of scope for this site and the lack of answers shows very clearly that it is *too* language specific.

Comment: @vectory - You don't say why you think it's out of scope when it has been clearly decided that writing systems are on-topic, and the apparent fact that no-one with sufficient knowledge of Armenian has posted an answer yet after a mere four days shows perhaps that it is too "language specific" to have been answered after four days. Let's see how it goes in the first few years.

Comment: language specific questions are out of scope. you might argue the script could be used to encode different languages. still it looks more like a language learning question. you might also just put in a bit of effort, search the translation for caligraphy and google that to see for yourself. best of luck